# Finding the $\min(X,Y)$ where X and Y are geometric random variables - Wrong Answer

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Problem:
Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent random variables having geometric
densities with parameters $p_1$ and $p_2$ respectively. Find the density of
$min(X,Y)$.
Answer:
Let $Z = \min(X,Y)$.
\begin{eqnarray*}
P( Z = 0 ) &=& P( X = 0 ) P(Y = 0) \\
P( Z = 1 ) &=& P( X = 1 ) P(Y < 1) +  P(Y = 1)P(X < 1) + P(x = 1)P(Y = 1) \\
P( Z = 2 ) &=& P( X = 2 ) P(Y < 2) +  P(Y = 2)P(X < 2) + P(x = 2)P(Y = 2) \\
P( Z = i ) &=& P( X = i ) P(Y < i) +  P(Y = i)P(X < i) + P(X = i)P(Y = i) \\
P( X = i ) &=& p_1(1-p_1)^{i} \\
P( Y = i ) &=& p_2(1-p_2)^{i} \\
P(X < i) &=& \sum_{i = 0}^{i-1} P( X = i ) =  \sum_{i = 0}^{i-1} p_1(1-p_1)^{i} \\
\end{eqnarray*}
We have a finite geometric series with $a = p_1$ and $r = 1 - p_1$.
\begin{eqnarray*}
P(X < i) &=& \frac{a(1-r^i)}{1 - r} = \frac{p_1(1-(1 - p_1)^i)}{1 - (1 - p_1)} \\
P(X < i) &=& \frac{p_1(1-(1 - p_1)^i)}{p_1} = 1 - (1 - p_1)^i \\
P(Y < i) &=& 1 - (1 - p_2)^i \\
P( Z = i ) &=& p_1(1-p_1)^i(1 - (1 - p_1)^i) + 
 p_2(1 - p_2)^i(1 - (1 - p_1)^i) + p_1 p_2 (1 - p_1)^i(1 - p_2)^i \\
\end{eqnarray*}
The book's answer is: geometric with parameter $p_1 + p_2 - p_1 p_2$.
That means, to me, that:
\begin{eqnarray*}
P( Z = i ) &=& p_1 + p_2 - p_1 p_2( 1 - (p1 + p_2 - p_1 p_2))^i \\
\end{eqnarray*}
which I believe is different than my answer. So, where did I go wrong?

Based upon the comments I got, I now have what I believe to be the correct answer:

Let $Z = min(X,Y)$.
\begin{eqnarray*}
P( Z = i ) &=& P ( X = i )P(Y > i) + P( Y = i)P(X > i) + P(X = i)P(Y = i)\\
P( X = i ) &=& p_1(1-p_1)^{i} \\
P( Y = i ) &=& p_2(1-p_2)^{i} \\
P( Y > i) &=& \sum_{j = i+1}^{\infty} P( Y = j ) =
 \sum_{j = i+1}^{\infty} p_2(1-p_2)^{j} \\
\end{eqnarray*}
Now we have a geometric series with $a = p_2(1 - p_2)^{i+1}$ and $r = 1 - p_2$.
\begin{eqnarray*}
P( Y > i) &=& \frac{p_2(1 - p_2)^{i+1}}{1 - (1 - p_2)}  = (1 - p_2)^{i+1} \\
P( X > i) &=& \frac{p_1(1 - p_1)^{i+1}}{1 - (1 - p_1)}  = (1 - p_1)^{i+1} \\
P( Z = i ) &=&
 p_1(1-p_1)^{i}( (1 - p_2)^{i+1} ) +  p_2(1-p_2)^{i}((1 - p_1)^{i+1} ) \\
 &+&  p_1(1-p_1)^{i}p_2(1-p_2)^{i} \\
P( Z = i ) &=& (1 - p_1)^i ( 1 - p_2)^i ( p_1(1 - p_2) + p_2(1 - p_2) + p_1 p_2 ) \\
P( Z = i ) &=&
 (1 - p_1)^i ( 1 - p_2)^i ( p_1 - p_1 p_2 + p_2 - p_2 p_1 + p_1 p_2 ) \\
P( Z = i ) &=&
 (1 - p_1)^i ( 1 - p_2)^i ( p_1 + p_2 - p_2 p_1  ) \\
P( Z = i ) &=& ((1 - p_1) ( 1 - p_2))^i ( p_1 + p_2 - p_2 p_1  ) \\
P( Z = i ) &=& ( p_1 + p_2 - p_2 p_1  ) ( 1 - (p_1 + p_2 - p_1 p_2 )^i\\
\end{eqnarray*}
Therefore $Z$ is a geometric random variable with parameter $p_1 + p_2 - p_1 p_2$.

Bob

Comment: The first wrong line: $P( Z = 1 )= P( X = 1 ) P(Y < 1) +  P(Y = 1)P(X < 1) + P(X = 1)P(Y = 1)$. If $Y<1$ then $Z=\min(X,Y)<1$. Replace both inequalities to the opposite ones. Or simply find $P(Z>i)=P(X>i)P(Y>i)$.

Comment: I do not understand why the first line is wrong.

Comment: If $X=1, Y=0$, then $Z=0$. And the first summand $P(X=1,Y<1)$ in $P(Z=1)$ states that $Z=1$ in this case.

Comment: $P\{Z=0\} =P(\{X=0\} \cup \{Y=0\}) =P(\{X=0\} +P \{Y=0\})-P(\{X=0\} \cap \{Y=0\}) = P\{X=0\} +P \{Y=0\}-P\{X=0\} P\{Y=0\}$

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Oh, this is the first line I missed, deciding that at zero everything is obvious and everything is in order! Thank you for noticing.